# A hole in the distribution of eigenvalues - is this real?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, spectral-theory, random-matrices

Plot the eigenvalues of many $n\times n$ real matrices in the complex plane, where the matrices are taken from a some distribution. For $n>7$, you can start to see a hole at the origin starting to form. From [Girko's Circular Law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GirkosCircularLaw.html) I'd expect the distribution to tend toward a solid disc (with no hole in it). Below, the eigenvalue distributions of $10\times 10$ matrices taken from three distributions are seen, all with holes in them. The bigger $n$ is, the larger the hole is. The distributions are:

1. All entries of all matrices are $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$
2. All entries of all matrices are $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$
3. The matrices are picked uniformly over the volume of a unit $n^2$-ball.

**Is this real (and not a bug in my code)? If it is, what is this phenomenon called?**

This seems to violate Girko's Circular Law, so what am I missing?

[image][image][image]

*Edit:* Here is my Matlab-code for generating these (without the scatterplot):

```
n = 10;
X = zeros(10^5,1);
Y = zeros(10^5,1);

for i = 1:10^5
    B = randn(n);
    C = eig(B);
    j = 1+4*(i-1);
    X(j:j+n-1) = real(C);
    Y(j:j+n-1) = imag(C);
end
```

Have I perhaps made some stupid mistake?

*2nd edit:* Here is a plot with the corrected code, as requested: [image]

Comment: Could it be an effect of finite precision in floating point numbers? You may test changing from double to single precision and see if the effect appears earlier (at lower values of $n$) to test this idea.

Comment: And as a quick sanity check, what is the quality of your random number generator? You're not using drand48() or something similar but some high quality random number generator, right?

Comment: How are you implementing this? Some quick testing in Mathematica doesn't reproduce any such hole.

Comment: @dioid I'm using Matlab's standard functions for such distributions, i.e., `randn(n)`, `rand(n)` and so on. I would think that that would be sufficient, but perhaps not?

Comment: @Semiclassical I've included my code.

Comment: Echoing the point re: precision made above, you might try including the 'double' argument in 'randn ' and see if that changes things.

Comment: @Semiclassical From the documentation of `randn()`: "the default datatype is 'double'." I implemented it anyway, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: It could probably be right. I found something similar for uniformly distributed matrices which seemed well known to have a name: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348679/random-matrices-eigenvalue-distribution

Comment: Try be careful and not **ever** use "i" in loops or variable names in Matlab as it is used for imaginary unit and can give really nasty difficult to find bugs.

Comment: So what explains the ‘crack’ along the x-axis in the plot with corrected code, anyone? I also note the symmetry about the x-axis, which does not seem at all random! I sees G's law describes the crack.

Comment: P.S. I mean the _exact_ symmetry, as far as I can see, about the x-axis – the superficial symmetry is not surprising.

Comment: @PJTraill The symmetry is easy to explain: All eigenvalues of real matrices are either real (i.e., they lie on the real number line) or come in complex conjugate pairs.

Comment: Of course – my fault for commenting after dinner and wine – I woke up the today and thought how futile my comments were. I wish alcohol and mathematics were as compatible as I feel they were when I was younger!

Comment: @PJTraill No worries! :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the problem is in how you're aggregating the eigenvalues into `X` and `Y`. `j` is incrementing by $4$ when it ought to be incrementing by $n = 10$, which has the effect of wiping out the smallest $6$ eigenvalues of almost every matrix, hence the hole. There's an easier way to do the aggregating that doesn't involve a `j` at all:

```
N = 10^4;
n = 10;
X = [];
Y = [];

for i = 1:N
    A = randn(n);
    E = eig(A);
    X = [X; real(E)];
    Y = [Y; imag(E)];
end

scatter(X, Y);
```

Comment: That seems to be it! Changing the 4 in original code to n should also fix the issue. Original code preallocates X and Y which should be good from a performance perspective, but there is a mismatch between vector size and loop over i, it should just be to 10^4. Anyways, original code just keeps first 4 eigenvalues and by the algorithm matlab uses they tend to be the ones largest in magnitude which explains the hole around the origin.

Comment: D'oh, you're right! It was some old code that I reused, and I forgot to change the 4 when changing the dimension to 10. Thanks!

Comment: Can we see a plot with the corrected code?

Comment: @brichins Certainly, see edit.

Answer (score 8):

Your plots instantly reminded me of something I'd seen before (click for a hi-res version):

[image]

Turns out that if your matrices have integer entries of bounded height, you do get holes, with the details depending on the distribution. What's more, there are all sorts of interesting and, to my knowledge, unsolved questions about this! [More details here.](http://steventhornton.ca/bohemian-eigenvalues/)

Given that real matrices can be approximated by rational ones, and bounded-height rationals can be multiplied by a sufficiently-large factor to give bounded-height integers, I wouldn't be surprised if there was some connection with the pattern you saw, even if it was only visible due to a bug.

Comment: And this makes me think (unsurprisingly?) of plots of roots of polynomials with integer coefficients: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/roots/

Comment: Thanks for the reference and picture, very beautiful!

Comment: In particular the set of [roots of monic degree 19 polynomials with coefficients in $\{-1, 1\}$](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/steventhornton.ca/Bohemian_Eigenvalues/Figure2_Original.png) make a wonderful image.

Answer (score 7):

Because you are overwriting some of the eigenvalues by using the offset of 4 rather than 10, you are preferentially overwriting the smaller eigenvalues. This is confirmed in [this SO selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704384/does-matlab-eig-always-returns-sorted-values), which states, for the Matlab algorithm:

> The eigenvalues TEND to be in descending order, but this is not assured at all. They tend to be in order because the largest tend to trickle out of the algorithm on top. Eig has no sort at the end to ensure that fact.

So while it isn't purposely sorted in descending order, the algorithm has this effect.